# WordPress - WP_Filesystem does not write or read

Tags: php, wordpress, file

On my server the WP_Filesystem does not work.
If I use the standard `file_put_contents` and `file_get_contents` the files are read and written just normally.

Do you know what may be the issue?

THIS DOES NOT WORK (RETURNING NO ERRORS):

```
global $wp_filesystem;
// Initialize the WP filesystem, no more using 'file-put-contents' function
if (empty($wp_filesystem)) {
    require_once (ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    WP_Filesystem();
}

if(!$wp_filesystem->put_contents( $path, $file_contents, 0644) ) {
    return esc_html__('Failed to put file', 'magellan');
}
```

THIS WORKS:

```
file_put_contents($path, $file_contents);
```

Comment: are you define the credentials for use WP_Filesystem

Comment: @mollie I have defined the FTP credentials in the wp-config file with no success. What else should I do?

Comment: where you using this code. in root folder of wordpress

Comment: @mollie in a theme functions